# Deserializing with Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, annotations, jackson

I need a way to deserialize this object:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "qwe"
    }
  ],
  "total": 0
}
```

to Row[] (i don't need "total") **WITHOUT USING OF WAPPER OBJECT**:

```
public class ReviewsWrapper {
    private Row[] rows;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer total;
}
```

directly deserializing it to Rows[]? If there was no "total" object, i would just deserialize using this method:

```
public static <T> T fromJsonWithRootName(InputStream is, Class<T> type, String rootName) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.reader(type).withRootName(rootName).readValue(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

passing "rows" as a rootName and will get Row[] as output. Is there any way to avoid using WrapperObject for Row[]? It's an Android project I define entities using **Jackson Annotations**.

Comment: Try

List<ParameterDTO> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<ParameterDTO>>(){}.getType());

Comment: I don't think you can. An alternative to your speculative attempt without the "total" property would be to configure your `ObjectMapper` with the `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`. Btw your JSON has an extra closing curly bracket.

Comment: @Mena fixed typo. I expect a solution without using UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE however.

Comment: @localhost I know, hence the comment-only. I don't have a solution - not sure there **is** one.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data Model classes should be like this

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

@JsonPropertyOrder({
"rows",
"total"
})
public class ReviewsWrapper {

@JsonProperty("rows")
private List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
@JsonProperty("total")
private long total;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The rows
*/
@JsonProperty("rows")
public List<Row> getRows() {
return rows;
}

/**
* 
* @param rows
* The rows
*/
@JsonProperty("rows")
public void setRows(List<Row> rows) {
this.rows = rows;
}

public ReviewsWrapper withRows(List<Row> rows) {
this.rows = rows;
return this;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The total
*/
@JsonProperty("total")
public long getTotal() {
return total;
}

/**
* 
* @param total
* The total
*/
@JsonProperty("total")
public void setTotal(long total) {
this.total = total;
}

public ReviewsWrapper withTotal(long total) {
this.total = total;
return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public ReviewsWrapper withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
return this;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Row.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"name"
})
public class Row {

@JsonProperty("id")
private long id;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
@JsonProperty("id")
public long getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Row withId(long id) {
this.id = id;
return this;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The name
*/
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Row withName(String name) {
this.name = name;
return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public Row withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
return this;
}
}
```

**Then in Java Class to de-serialize using Jackson use below code**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();

JsonParser jp = jf.createJsonParser("your json data as a String");

ReviewsWrapper reviewWrapper = mapper.readValue(jp,ReviewsWrapper.class);
```

after this You can get all your response from "ReviewsWrapper.class"

**Here is Example using JsonNode try this. is this what you want?**

Here is one Example using Nodes.

```
public class App {
    public static class Foo {
        public int foo;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\"someArray\":[{\"foo\":5},{\"foo\":6},{\"foo\":7}]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
        node = node.get("someArray");
        TypeReference<List<Foo>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Foo>>(){};
        List<Foo> list = mapper.readValue(node.traverse(), typeRef);
        for (Foo f : list) {
            System.out.println(f.foo);
        } }}
```

Comment: What i want is to AVOID using any wrapper.

Comment: then probably u can read Nodes of this JsonParser and can fetch the values of row. for this You can write this line                                                   JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jp);

Comment: and other way You can just use simple way of parsing which Android provides using JsonObject and JsonArray. If you are doing Using Jackson then its very useful to create model classes and use them. it makes your code perfect, and use to use. and if you want to pass those objects use Parcel able to pass anywhere in Your project.